# In which order the jmeter was working in Listener?

Tags: testing, jmeter

I have 10 Http Request samplers in my jmeter. I have specified the Number of Threads as 2. So the total of requests is 20.

If i run Jmeter the following one of way it should run:

1. first Run Thread1 requests completed for all 10 Http requests and Run the Thread2 requests;
2. or randomly run two threads http requests.

Which order jmeter will follow?
Also which Listener i need to use if want to know the jmeter running order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on ramp-up time :

- if you set it to 0, then the 2 threads will run simultaneously, and you cannot tell about the order of the 20 requests
- if you set ramp up to a very big value, you could have thread 1 requests end then thread 2 requests start but that's not what you want from load tests

Finally you can use view results in tree or table but just during script debug.

Comment: Thank you.if i specify ramp up value then thread created within the specified time.correct? I  think this is not right to do test in jmeter.